# How to fix these issue in my framing

Tags: framing, frame

i did my first frame ever

and here are the issues i faced I wonder if someone can guide me on how to fix them

1- The stud i bought are actually bent in the centre like this

[image]

2- the bottom pressure-treated wood is twisted, how to fix that

you can see in this photo

[image]

3- because of the vent I had to cut the last stud, is this the right thing to do

you can see that in this photo

[image]

4- does the finished job look ok?

i did not nail it to the ground or the ceiling beams yet

you can see that in this photo

[image]

Comment: I'd be putting some horizontal pieces between all those uprights. And you mention nailing. Screwing allows the 'joints' to be made tighter. And easier to dismantle if needed in the future!

Comment: An issue I see is at the corner where the new meets the existing wall. You don't have anything in the insulated wall to support the drywall in that corner.

Comment: @brhans shall i nail it to the insulated wall?

Comment: You need to build a proper corner there to support the drywall by adding another 2x4 behind that short one, sticking out to the left by at least an inch. I'd us construction screws through the short stud to attach the new corner support.

Answer (score 2):

Twisted wood is going to happen. To minimize the twist, buy the straightest wood you can get off the stack (look down the long edge and the crooked wood is easy to spot) and nail it together as soon as you can. Depending on the grain, most wood will distort (twist, warp, cup, or bow) as it dries. If there is something to resist that distortion (like being attached to a concrete floor or other framing member) the twist can be minimized. To fix yours, use some #8x3 1/2" deck screws to pull the wood together.

The rest of the wall looks just fine. Make sure there is blocking installed on the insulated wall to support the last (short) stud. I couldn't tell from the picture if there was an existing stud behind it or not.

Comment: shall i nail it to the insulated wall?

Comment: Is there a stud on the insulated wall behind you're newly constructed wall? If yes, then nail the shortened 2x4 to that. If not, then install some blocking on the insulated wall and nail to that. Do a search on "framing blocking" if you need some more details.